# The name 'trace' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, trace

By default, when creating a project, Visual Studio defines the Debug and Trace constants for the debug mode, and Trace only for the release mode.

I've set up a bare project which just outputs two logs, one with Trace and one with Debug :

```
// etc.
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DebugTrace
{
   public partial class App : Application
   {    
       // [...]

       private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("[Debug] Application launching");
           Trace.WriteLine("[Release] Application launching");
       }

       // [...]
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio tells me that :

```
Error   3   The name 'Trace' does not exist in the current context  C:\Dev\WP7\DebugTrace\DebugTrace\DebugTrace\App.xaml.cs 68  7   DebugTrace
```

Debug is working as expected.

I've searched a bit, and nobody seems to have this error. The project has been just created, I didn't touch anything, and I don't understand why Trace is not working although TRACE constant is defined.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 express with a Windows Phone project.

Comment: post the line of code where the error occurs

Comment: It should be Trace (capital T)

Comment: and don't forget the `using System.Diagnostics;`

Comment: I've added the code. The import is there too.

Comment: Please post the actual code, and the actual error-message - copy-pasted!

Comment: Done. But it's almost the same, what I try to do is really trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Trace is not available for Window Phone 7. You might want to use some custom library for writing out Trace information through a WebService.

For example take a look at [this](http://silverlightlogging.codeplex.com/) and [this](http://www.devtracer.com/trace-monitor/howto_silverlight.aspx)

Trace in Windows Phone 7 won't make much sense because you shouldn't store that info on User's phone. Instead you should pass it to a webservice which can write it out at a place where developer can get it

Comment: Yep, it looks like you're right. Nevertheless, it could have been useful for me. Thanks.